# Proper way to add types to Redux-toolkit reducer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, types, redux-toolkit

I am fairly new to TypeScript and I want to achieve a where:

```
interface ActionType {
  fieldName: {any one key in the interface FormStateType given below like as 'name', 'age', 'weight' };
  value: {corresponding type to that key like string for name, and so on};
}

interface FormStateType {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  weight: number;
}
```

I want to add the type to a reducer so that the payload contains the key of the value to be changed and the updated value. In simple words, my payload would be so -> ("age", 18).
How can I implement it without the editor showing me errors?
[image: Warning message on VS code]

Answer (score 1):

I also was in a similar situation and had no idea how to change it. I went threw more than 100 websites and StackOverflow questions. And I also bumped into your question which was close to what I was looking for. I was so happy to see your code but so sad to see no answer. So I thought if I find a way I will come back and give you one way to solve it. I am also not an expert in Typescript and am not sure if this is correct but because this worked for me hope my code could give you a little hint.

```js
type ActionType<T extends keyof FormStateType>{
  fieldName: T;
  value: FormStateType[T];
}

setNewFormData:  <T extends keyof FormStateType> (state : FormStateType, action : PayloadAction<ActionType<T>>) => {
  
},
```

Hope there are more answers and more typescript code written in public in the future.

Happy coding :)